# IOS and Parse.com - How do I set an ACL for a managed object?

Tags: ios, core-data, webservice-client, parse-platform

I have three managed objects in an iOS app where the backend will be Parse.com.

I know how to set an Access Control List for a regular object. How do I achieve the same goal with a managed object?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
someManagedObject.ACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
```

Comment: I really don't know why you would need to do this locally.

Answer (score 1):

Found this in documentation for a workaround:

https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#security-recommendations/iOS

> To help ensure that your users' data is secure by default, you can set a default ACL to be applied to all newly-created PFObjects:

```
[PFACL setDefaultACL:[PFACL ACL] withAccessForCurrentUser:YES];
```

So after login to Parse.com, the Parse Library can take care for your secure object handling.
You have your own business logic, and when trying to communicate with Parse and sending models it will automatically add ACL to your objects. Later Parse will only download that object
s, that match the logged-in user's ACL.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your trying to help. I actually knew this one and have applied it. It doesn't seem to work with managed objects, (or I'm using it incorrectly). But I'm working with the Parse engineers to try to figure it out. I posted here in case that someone else had solved it.